# Как запустить симуляцию в avrStudio?

Tags: eclipse, avr, avr-gcc

Допустим есть проект helloWorld для atmega8. 
Если его собирать с помощью IAR, то можно выставить формат ubrof8 и потом запустить его в симуляторе AvrStudio

А как сгенерить формат файла, который можно былоб просимулировать в AvrStudio используя avr-gcc?

Ну другими словами, используя linux и eclipse можно ли как-то сгенерить формат файла для запуска симуляции под AvrStudio

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос поставлен не совсем корректно.Если стоит цель писать код в Eclipse,а отладку в режиме симуляции запускать в Avr Studio,то достаточно в студии создать проект,а исходники проекта открывать в требуемой IDE,студия видит изменения и перезагружает файлы.Я сам так делаю,поскольку редактор в 4-й студии вырвиглазный.

Comment: Ох, спасиб за ответ ). А собирать проект AVR-студией или Eclipsом? Раньше можно было помню в IAR задать формат выходного файла вроде как-то назывался ubrof8 и тогда точто накомпилит IAR открыть в студии и просимулировать. Вот и думал может есть такая же возможность и для Eclipse.